# Export multiple ranges to a single PDF using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to write a macro to cycle through a dropdown menu. Everytime the value in the drop down changes it will change the values on the worksheet. I won't to capture a range of the worksheet for every value in the dropdown in a VBA array and then export all of these ranges to single PDF. I'm able to export them one at a time to multiple PDFs but this isn't the objective. The problem I seem to be having is storing the different ranges in an Array.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub bill_exporter()
' Macro to export billing estimates to a single pdf

'Define Filenames and ranges
Dim myfile As String
Dim billsheet As Worksheet
Dim print_area As Excel.Range
Dim site As Range
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim i As Integer


i = 0
myfile = Range("filename").Value
Set billsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mock Bill")

For Each site In Range("meters")

    billsheet.Calculate
    billsheet.Range("$R$10").Value = site

    'Create Vertical Page Breaks
    billsheet.VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("C3")
    billsheet.VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("R3")

    'Set Print Area
    Set print_area = billsheet.Range("C3:R50")

    Set arr(i) = print_area.Value

    i = i + 1

Next site

Array(arr).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=myfile

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance for any assistance!

Comment: you could always copy and paste the data you want onto a new worksheet formatted appropriately for the PDF export, export to PDF, then delete the sheet.

Comment: Thanks CustodianOfCode... That's exactly what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 0):

So you can't collect them all into a single array, solution is to create multiple dummy sheets and delete them when done: